# What does the parameter $something=null mean in PHP?

Tags: php, function

We got a PHP file in school with some functions and one of them is the following:

```
function serviceRec($db,$table,$afields=null,$avalues=null){ .... }
```

My question: What does the `$afields=null` and `$avalues=null` mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function serviceRec($db,$table,$afields=null,$avalues=null){ .... }
```

It means that, when you call your function and don't pass those parameters then it'll by default place value as `null`

**Example :**

```
function hello($name = "anonymous"){
    return "Hello $name \n";
}

echo hello();//Hello anonymous
echo hello("BigSeeProduction");//Hello BigSeeProduction
```

[**DOCS**](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Answer (score 2):

It Means it's the default value. So when u don't fill this parameter it will be set as null.

See the man here :
[PHP.net : default value function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Answer (score 2):

These assignments are default values. If you were to call the function as e.g.

```
serviceRec($a, $b)
```

the omitted parameters would be assumed to be `null`. If, on the other hand, you called the function as e.g.

```
serviceRec($a, $b, $c, $d)
```

`$afields` would be set to `$c` and `$avalues` to `$d`.

Of course, you could also call with 3 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

That indicates, that if you leave that parameter out(Don't specify it at all), the value after the `=`, in this case `null` is used. So if you don't care about these parameters just leave them out. It has the same effect as just supllying `null`.